# In a relational database how would I represent stock data with arbitrary depth?

Tags: sql, database-design

For example a stock can have a best bid price.  It can also have a second best price, third best price and so on down to the nth best price. N is unknown and varying.  How can I represent this in a relational database?

Comment: What have you thought of so far?

Comment: Could you create a two column table to hold the information. Something like stockID and price? You could then sort them to figure out how a price stacks up against the rest?

Comment: Does this have to be in a relational database?  You could use an object database (they tend to excel at this sort of storage).

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply, the Stock table would have a one-to-many relationship with BidPrice table.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it:

```
StockTable:

StockID  | Name
----------------
1        | Item 1 
2        | Item 3

StockPricesTable:

StockId  | Price
-----------------
1        | 1.25
1        | 2.25
1        | 3.25
2        | 1.55
2        | 1.75
2        | 1.95
2        | 2.25
2        | 1.25
2        | 1.25
```

I would probably leave the "nth best price" out of the table definition and put that logic in your query.  You could also add a Primary Key value to the StockPricesTable if needed.